# Unexplained Behavior with std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

In Stepping through some weird segmentation fault causing code, I found that after the assignment of one vector to another, the receiving vector arbitrarily corrupts. The following is a code snippet from a copy constructor of a class which has a data member `vector<Piece> *pieces` which is a dynamically allocated array containing vectors of type `Piece`.

```
ClassName::ClassName(const Class &other) // copy constructor of class
{
  ...
  for(SIDE_t s = 0; s < sides; s++)
  {
    pieces[s].reserve(other.pieces[s].size());
    pieces[s] = other.pieces[s];   //vector is completely valid here
    for(Uint8 p = 0; p < pieces[s].size(); p++)
    {
     //it continues validity throughout loop
      if(other.pieces[s][p].getCell() != NULL)
    pieces[s][p].setCell(cells + (other.pieces[s][p].getCell() - other.cells));

      if(pieces[s][p].getCell() == NULL)
        out.push_back(&pieces[s][p]);
    }
    if(other.flags[s] != NULL)
      flags[s] = getPiece(other.flags[s]->getValue(), other.flags[s]->getSide());
       // vector is invalid in scope of getPiece, which receives completely valid arguments
    else
      flags[s] = NULL;
  }
}

Piece * const ClassName::getPiece(const Uint8 num, const SIDE_t s) const 
{
    return (num>nPieces || s>sides || num == 0)? NULL:&pieces[s][num-1];
  // Right here during the member access function of pieces,
  // it is clear that the vector was corrupted some how
}
```

Essentially during debugging, I would step into `pieces[s]` member access function. In the loop body, it is evident that `m_start` has a valid address, however when it exits the loop body and calls the index operator on `pieces[s]` in `getPiece`, m_start is NULL. There are no operations performed on `pieces[s]` between the last iteration of the loop when `m_start` is valid, and in `getPiece` when during the same call of the index operator as in the loop body, `m_start` is NULL. Any insight on my misuse of std::vector or bugs in std::vector would be appreciated.

Comment: `std::vector<Piece> *pieces` ?? Why not `std::vector<std::vector<Piece>> pieces` ?

Comment: `vector` does not belong to STDs, it belongs to `std`.

Comment: did you forget `ClassName::` on `getPiece`?

Comment: @Serdalis sorry about that, I'll fix it
PetrBudnik ever heard of xkcd. XKCD is a comic. Visit his info page
Walter that wasn't the question

Comment: @bathtub its ok, but if you forgot it in the code as well that's probably your problem.

Comment: @Serdalis, in the actual code it's inline, in the header file. I moved it for convenience. My code compiles by the way. It's a seg fault that sets it off due to NULL m_start

Comment: *my misuse of std::vector or bugs in std::vector* ... most likely it's the former; specifically screwing around with a dynamically allocated array of vectors, instead of another vector to contain them. Echoing Walter's comment, use `std::vector<std::vector<Piece>> pieces;`

Comment: The thing is however, ALL the code works except for when that function is called at that point. When it's called anywhere else it works fine.

Comment: this codes looks just weird ... `Uint8` where a `std::size_t` belongs, unnecessary `reserve()` when a copy will happen in the next line

Comment: @Walter if the reserve isn't present, a similar yet different situation occurs wherein during the copy, the capacity function returns 0, and rather than allocating more memory, it sets m_start, m_finish, and end_of_storage to NULL explicitly, as seen through stepping through the code

Comment: Are you sure that `return (num>nPieces || s>sides || num == 0)? NULL:&pieces[s][num-1];` should not be `return (num>nPieces-1 || s>sides-1 || num == 0)? NULL:&pieces[s][num-1];`?

Comment: you say the class has a data-member `pieces`, that function wouldn't be able to access that data-member unless it is part of the same class. You are far better off using a `static` member function. It's safer and better form. Also function bodies don't belong in header files and never assume a function is inlined. The compiler does what it wants no matter what you tell it (that and in debugging nothing is inlined).

Comment: I am sure that that is not the problem, if that were an issue, `this` would be NULL in the operator call as opposed to its members.

Comment: Thanks for the info Serdalis, however it is indeed part of the same class. I don't see why it shouldn't be a member function however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you have an access violation here:

```
return (num>nPieces || s>sides || num == 0)? NULL:&pieces[s][num-1];
```

First (as pointed out by Petr), it should read `s>=sides`.

Second, `s` here is not the same as `s` in the caller. So `pieces[s]` may not have been assigned yet and is an empty vector. To test it use

```
return (num>nPieces || s>=sides || num == 0)? NULL : &(pieces[s].at(num-1));
```

Btw, all this would have been avoided had you simply used

```
std::vector<std::vector<Piece>>
```

and copied the whole thing.

Comment: Not at all. I step into the operator call at this point, and num-1 is clearly less than size. Before the function executes, m_start is already NULL.

Comment: I think that's it. Yes, it seems that putting a second loop that iterates through the sides after the first one would indeed work.

Comment: Not exactly "avoided" but yes that does seem to be better. I don't remember why I decided against it before